# How to know the name of the excel file you link in the formula EPPLUS

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

In order to find out worksheet relationship, I am using EPPLUS to read the formula inside the cell of excel using this code:

```
string cellValue = workSheet.Cells[row, col].Formula
```

- For cell reference to another worksheet **in the same work book**. For example, in the same workbook, a cell in Sheet1 refer to another cell in Sheet2

result of cellValue will like Sheet2!A1

Ok, I know that it will link to Sheet2 in the same workbook

- For cell reference to another worksheet **in other work book**. For example, a cell in Sheet1 workbook A refer to another cell in Sheet1 in workbook B

result of cellValue will like [1]Sheet1!A1

The name of the work B is not shown, it just show [1] like example above. I won't know what is [1].

Whether any method help me know that [1] is workbook B and the location of workbook B ?

I have google but don't find out yet.

Thank you.